# Creating Gradle Tasks in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I'm new to both tools, but why is it that sometimes I can see the tasks from the gradle.build file under the "Run Tasks" section in IntlliJ, and other times I can't?

In other words why does gradle not always identify my tasks?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to refresh all gradle projects for new tasks to be recognised. This can be done by pressing this button in the `Gradle projects` view:

[image: Gradle projects view refresh all]

Once this is done, you should see your new tasks in the list.

Comment: it did supposed to help but even after refresh it didn't work. it worked after closing the project and re-imoprt  the build.gradle. it's really my first steps in this application hope to get more familiar with it soon :).